# Ethernet stuck in an "Identifiying... No ethernet" loop after every boot, need to renew IP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

This started happening a few days ago, I don't remember doing anything that could cause this issue.
The cable is fine, so is the port. Tried resetting the adapter settings, resetting the router and the modem, uninstalled/reinstalled the network driver, nothing helps.
ipconfig /renew fixes it, but it usually just says "Can't perform this operation while ethernet has it's media disconnected" and "User cancelled the operation". I basically had to make a batch file that runs the command on repeat and after some 20 minutes it fixes the issue.
I'm on Windows 10 with all of the updates installed.
The only noteworthy thing i found in the event viewer is that the DHCP client gets shutdown as soon as it starts, and a bunch of DCOM errors afterward (ID 10016 and 7026). Checking the Network Adapter events shows nothing of note, the latest thing it shows is removing and installing it a few days back, probably from when i first encountered this issue and i tried fixing it by doing that. Both sfc /snannow and Dism didn't find anything wrong.
OK, so after booting up my computer today the issue seemed to have gone away, I have no clue what fixed it. I have tried using a different cable and router port before, so it *could* be the port on the computer, but I doubt it since it works fine now. Again, I have no idea why the ethernet works now, IP setting is still on DHCP.

Comment: Try to check/analyze the `System Logs` using the **Event Viewer** for any not "ordinary" messages related to the network components. What is your operating system?

Comment: If you're on Windows, test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: @Meremam: In Windows you can open _Network Adapter_ properties, select the **Events** tab and click on **View All Events...** button: can provide some useful information to found the problem. By the way, what is you network connection IP assignment:  _MANUAL_ or _AUTOMATIC (DHCP)_? If it's _AUTOMATIC_ this might be a problem.

Comment: @Meremam: Try to configure the TCP/IP protocol on the adapter to use Static IP. More likely you are using, for example, Wi-Fi connection that not stable and is disconnecting from time to time.

Comment: @Jackdaw: My computer doesn't have a wireless adapter so it can't be using an unstable Wi-Fi, but I'll try to set a static IP a bit later since I still have to do something on the PC and I'd rather not risk it not working and having to go through the whole process again.

Comment: It sounds like either the cable or the port on one of the two sides is bad. What did you do to rule that out?

Comment: @Meremam: Usual computer issues caused by a cat... :)